How to remove the circled numbers from the image and obtain an image without circled numbers?
Initial image:


Target image:


My personal attempt was as follows, but I didn't completely clean it up.
In the context, "image" refers to the initial image.
image = Import["https://i.sstatic.net/pBRwlXEf.png"];
grayImage = ColorConvert[image, "Grayscale"];
threshold = 0.5;
binaryImage = Binarize[grayImage, threshold];
smallObjectsRemoved = Opening[binaryImage, 2];
Show[image, Image[smallObjectsRemoved]]



Another option is to select the smallest component by Circularity
img = Import["https://i.sstatic.net/pBRwlXEf.png"];
ColorNegate@
 SelectComponents[ColorNegate@Binarize@img, "Circularity", 1]



You can use DeleteSmallComponents.
img = Import["https://i.sstatic.net/pBRwlXEf.png"];
ColorNegate@DeleteSmallComponents[ColorNegate@Binarize[img], 100]



This is maybe better: neg = ColorNegate@ image; ColorNegate@ ImageMultiply[neg, Dilation[DeleteSmallComponents@ Binarize@ neg, 1]] (boundaries of lines less affected according to ImageDifference[]). (+1)
